# JPA неправильная последовательность INSERT

Tags: java, orm, jpa

При персисте нового объекта с коллекцией происходит ошибка

> FK not found

Вот маппинг:

```
@Entity(name = "CRM_TASKDEPARTURE")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = TaskType.Consts.VISIT_ID)
public class TaskVisit extends Task {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<TaskVisitAddress> addresses = new ArrayList();

public TaskVisit() { }


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,mappedBy =    "taskVisit")
public List<TaskVisitAddress> getAddresses() {
return addresses;
   }
}
```

Маппинг объекта коллекции:

```
@Entity(name = "CRM_TaskDepartureAddress")
public class TaskVisitAddress implements Serializable {
...any fields 
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TASKID")
public TaskVisit getTaskVisit() {
return taskVisit;
}
@Id
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSONADDRESSID")
 public PersonAddress getPersonAddress() {
 return personAddress;
   }
}
```

`InheritanceType.JOINED` Абстрактного класса `Task`.

Последовательность инсертов в таблицы:

1. `CRM_TASK`
2. `CRM_TaskDepartureAddress`
3. `CRM_TASKDEPARTURE`

2 и 3 по логике ведь должно сначала быть инсерт в `CRM_TASKDEPARTURE`, а потом уже `CRM_TaskDepartureAddress`, т.к. `CRM_TaskDepartureAddress` имеет `FK` на `CRM_TASKDEPARTURE`, а не наоборот. В чем может быть ошибка ?

P.s. имплементация JPA - *eclipselink 2.6.1*

Comment: Действительно такая последовательность insert-ов? При добавлении TaskVisitAddress в коллекцию не забываете установить TaskVisitAddress.taskVisit или надеетесь, что jpa это сделает за вас?

Comment: @banme 2 TaskVisitAddress.taskVisit ставится, это баг, я надеюсь, что кто-то знает как обойти без помощи костыля это.

Comment: @banme 2 TaskVisitAddress.taskVisit ставится, это баг (коллекция считает PK ID`шник абстрактного класса(CRM_TASK), а не CRM_TASKDEPARTURE), я надеюсь, что кто-то знает как обойти без помощи костыля это.

Comment: Можно наследование немного переиначить. Сделать InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE, а CRM_TASKDEPARTURE в TaskVisit объявить @SecondaryTable. Других наследников Task аналогично. Если такой вариант годится, может и получится обмануть eclipselink?